# Deployment Link Switches to Localhost After Stripe Payment or Payment cancelation in MERN App

Tags: javascript, express, stripe-payments

I have deployed a MERN (MongoDB, Express.js, React, Node.js) e-commerce app with Stripe integration. The deployment is done using Render for the server side and Netlify for the client side.
**Problem**:

After a successful payment using the Stripe integration, the link changes from the deployment link (e.g., https://greenmind-shop.netlify.app) to http://localhost:5173/. This causes subsequent sections of the site to load with localhost links instead of the deployment link.

**Relevant Code:**

Below is the relevant code snippet from my Stripe route on the server side:

javascript

```
stripe.checkout.sessions
    .create({
      line_items,
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}success`,
      cancel_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}cart`,
    })
    .then((session) => {
      res.send({ url: session.url });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error creating checkout session:', error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error creating checkout session' });
    });
});
```

In my .env I do have the localhost as value for CLIENT_URL. I am unsure how to handle it in a deploy environment as updating it to the deploy link does not work either.

I've tried updating the CLIENT_URL environment variable on Netlify to the deployment link, but the issue persists.
I have also tried changing the .env value for CLIENT_URL to the deployment link and that did not work either. I would get error: Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site".

How can I ensure that the deployment link remains consistent throughout the app after a successful Stripe payment, and how should I adjust the success_url and cancel_url in the Stripe route to avoid switching to localhost?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!